# How can I load an .xls file to a mysql database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, xls

I want the exact opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490866/mysql-to-xls-using-php).

I want to load a .xls file full of emails into a database column.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ponies said, you will have to first "Save As > CSV" then upload and do whatever.  Often permissions will not allow that SQL statement however.  My personal favorite is using [csv2sql.com](http://csv2sql.com) because it will do the heavy lifting and give you the SQL to just execute, however you could use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) which would be more secure, and something you can implement into a script.

With fgetcsv, you could do something like this assuming you just had a one column file with the email addresses listed:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        //echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if ($c==0){
                 //This is the first column
                 //Just run a generic MySQL insert command here (see below for link for more info on this)
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Tutorial on PHP MySQL Insert: at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_insert.asp).  That should get you going on this endeavor.

Answer (score 1):

1. Export the Excel spreadsheet to CSV format
2. Use [MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to use the CSV file created in Step 1, using:

   ```
   LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
     IGNORE 1 LINES;
   ```

The file will have to be locally accessible to the MySQL instance, so you'll have to upload it if the server isn't physically accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), which can read most Excel file formats (BIFF5, BIFF8, spreadsheetML). Unfortunately the project's docs are in a word file, so can't link directly to the specific section, but it's section 6.4.1 / page 37 of this [file](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/26478#DownloadId=145938).