# How to make a excel from php without phpexcel?

Tags: php, excel

Well I have been searching for a while (google,here & other pages) and I haven't found a solution for me.

I have a php file that makes a table from querys, but I need to make an xls file and send it via email, my issue is, I need this to be automatic without force-download header.

I read about phpexcel but if I use that library, I need to remake whole php code.

I tried using part of this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2512686/5586647

Is there a way to accomplish this without PHPExcel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a csv by putting your data into a variable and then adding a "\t" after each column and a "\r" when you want to end a row. Write that string out to a file, then send an email out with that file as the attachment. I suggest [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer%20%22%20PHPMailer) since it makes doing file attachments in emails very easy.

Comment: Well I already made it, using another library and only adding kinda 10 more code lines, anyway thank you for your help :)